# Lower bound for distance between matrices from singular values

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A,B \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times m}$  be rank $r$ matrices and let

$$
A=U_A \Sigma_A V_A^* \quad \quad \quad B=U_B \Sigma_B V_B^*
$$
be the singular value decompositions for $A$ and $B$, and diagonal entries of $\Sigma_A$ and $\Sigma_B$ are ordered from largest to smallest

I would like to show
$$
\|A-B\| \geq \|\Sigma_A-\Sigma_B\|
$$
where $\|\cdot \|$ is the Frobenius norm or the spectral norm. (I'd prefer to do it for both eventually.)

So far I have found that for the Frobenius norm the problem is closely related to the [orthogonal Procrustes problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_Procrustes_problem). Since the spectral and frobenius norm are invariant under left or right unitary multiplication we can assume $A=\Sigma_A$. If we further take $U_B=I$ or $V_B=I$ then the result flows from the linked wiki.

Using a similar approach to the wiki I have shown that for the Frobenius norm it is equivalent to show that
$$
tr(U \Sigma_A V \Sigma_B) \leq tr(\Sigma_A \Sigma_B)
$$
for any unitaries $U$ and $V$, where $tr$ is the trace.

I have had less success working with the spectral norm, but generated several million matrix pairs across chosen values of $n,m,r$ and did not find a counter example.

I did show the bound holds in the rank one case.

Comment: Presumably you're using the convention in SVD that the singular values are listed in decreasing order.  Otherwise you could have $A=B$ but $\Sigma_A \ne \Sigma_B$.

Comment: Yes, singular values are ordered here. I'll edit for clarity

Comment: @Eric: Were you able to solve this? I have also shown that $ \| A - B \|_F \geq \| \Sigma_A - \Sigma_B \|_F$, but stuck on the spectral norm.

Comment: @VHarisop Unfortunately I have not managed to solve it for the spectral norm. The frob norm is good enough form my setting, so I not thinking about it much anymore, although I ideally think about it sometimes. I'll post here if I figure it out at some point. I'd certainly still be interested in seeing a solution if you think of one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\sigma_1(X)\geq\cdots\geq\sigma_n(X)$ denote the singular values of a $n\times n$ matrix $X$ in decreasing order.

For spectral norm $\|\cdot\|_2,$ we need to show a Lipschitz bound

$$|\sigma_i(A)-\sigma_i(B)|\leq \|A-B\|_2$$

for each $1\leq i\leq n.$

This is Golub-van Loan, Matrix Computations, Corollary 8.6.2. It is an easy consequence of the minmax characterization of singular values.